# How do I create a regular expression to negate a string but include anything else

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I'm trying to create a regex for apache that will ignore certain strings, but will use anything else. Ive tried many different methods however i just can't seem to get it correct.

for example

i want it to ignore

ignore.mysite.com

but anything else i want it to use

*.mysite.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a regex that matches `whatever.mysite.com` where `whatever` is any possible hostname, but you want the regex not to match `ignore.mysite.com`, then try this:

```
^(?!ignore)[a-z0-9-]+\.mysite\.com
```

The trick is to use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want this regular expressions for mod_rewrite, you can use [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with negation, just like this:

```
   RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  !^ignore.example.com$
   RewriteRule ....
```

You can find more, of course, in documentation.

Comment: I was hoping to do this in the server alias portion of a virtual host

Comment: In this case, just define another virtual host ignore.example.com before *.example.com

Comment: basically what i have is three sites the default which i want to be either example.com or www.example.com, next i have staging.example.com and finally devel.example.com which i want anything else (devel.example.com or * aside from staging) to be redirected to. Right now i have each one of these sites separated into a separate vhost